# How to fix "Exception thrown: read access violation. **Surface** was nullptr. occurred" in SDL2 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl-2

Im trying to learn SDL2 with c++,

and every time I try to fill a surface i get this error, searched on the internet for a solution and haven`t found one yet:

```
SDL_Surface* Surface = NULL;
```

```
SDL_FillRect(Surface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(Surface->format, 0, 255, 0));
```

every time I run this, it doesn't show an error but it does break the code and shows an X and a little box with the text "Exception thrown: read access violation. Surface was nullptr." near the FillRect line. I can click "Copy Details" and then it copies "Exception thrown: read access violation.
** Surface ** was nullptr. occurred"

Comment: What's not clear in that error message? `Surface` is very clearly a `nullptr`.

Comment: Just as you usually can't `int *foo = NULL; foo[0] = 0;` you can't access a surface that haven't been created. What do you intend to use it for? Manually creating surface with e.g. `SDL_CreateRGBSurface` would do, but what then? You probably should edit question to include code fragment with intended usage, e.g. putting image on screen (but then what is screen? why not fill screen itself)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use something like

```
SDL_CreateRGBSurface
```

instead for `NULL`. Because you cant write to something that doesn't exist in memory.